# Informix: How to average result from Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, informix, user-defined-functions

Let's say I have this function `sp_func(startdate, enddate)`. 
To call the function itself I use `CALL sp_func(startdate, enddate);`.

The function will return a table consisting of:

```
id   name      time
1    smith     3.2
2    neo       8.2
3    morpheus  2.4
```

What I want to do is to average the time from that function.
I tried with `SELECT AVG(time) FROM sp_func(startdate, enddate)` but it didn't work. Syntax error occurred. I'm not sure what's the exact syntax for this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The magic keyword is `TABLE`.  Here's a script demonstrating the solution:

### Dummy procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_func(begin_date DATE, end_date DATE)
    RETURNING INTEGER AS id, VARCHAR(10) AS NAME, DECIMAL(5,2) AS TIME;

    RETURN 1, "smith",     3.2 WITH RESUME;
    RETURN 2, "neo",       8.2 WITH RESUME;
    RETURN 3, "morpheus",  2.4;

END PROCEDURE;

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_func('2012-01-01', '2012-12-31');
```

#### Output

```
1   smith      3.20
2   neo        8.20
3   morpheus   2.40
```

### Main SELECT statement

```
SELECT AVG(a.TIME)
FROM TABLE(PROCEDURE sp_func('2012-01-01', '2012-12-31')) AS A(id, name, time)
;
```

#### Output

```
4.6
```

The AS clause with the column names was necessary, even though the procedure names its return values.

This syntax is documented in the Informix Guide to SQL: Syntax manual, under the SELECT statement in chapter 2, and the sub-heading is 'Iterator Functions (IDS)' (p2-638 in the copy of ids-sqs_bookmap.pdf for 11.70 that I have).

Comment: thanks for the cleanup and answer. Im able to run your dummy function and select just fine. But when I try with my SP, i get illegal sql statement in spl routine. BTW, the a.TIME <-- why the 'TIME' need to be in capital letter? and I checked the location of the sp_func, it's in 'FUNCTION' folder, not in the TABLE folder. Is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: TIME did not need to be capitalized; SQL is case-insensitive.  I just have an SQL formatter that recognizes TIME as a keyword and I didn't convert to lower-case or mixed-case.  There are some statements that are not allowed in a routine that is going to be used as an Iterator Function.  I think that update operations are prohibited; so probably are DDL statements.  Given the body of the procedure, I could probably guess swiftly which is the troublesome statement.  The choice of FUNCTION vs PROCEDURE is, AFAIK, basically immaterial.